# Get zoho emails in my rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mail-server, zoho

I am trying to fetch emails received and sent from zoho account.
I want to trace all the emails coming to me in outlook or I am sending from outlook.

I have seen zohoCRM, rubyzoho but not able to get things done.
Any suggestions on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a way to build a simple email client with ruby.

There is a simple [Ruby Mail library](https://github.com/mikel/mail) which can get the work done for you. For quick reference, you can check the section ["Getting email from a POP server"](https://github.com/mikel/mail#getting-emails-from-a-pop-server)

Zoho supports [POP Access](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/pop-access.html). You should be able to get the access details from there and use it.

The Ruby mail library also support IMAP access and so does Zoho.

Comment: thanks for quick reply, where should I spcify 'Mail.defaults do' values

Comment: If it is global for the whole app, you could create an initialiser and add the defaults there so that they are set when the rails application is loaded. You could create an initialiser as `config/initializers/mail_pop_defaults.rb` and add the code there.

Comment: Thanks again, I already added mail.rb in initializers, but then when I excute `rails console` it gives me error as `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Mail (NameError)`

Comment: Mail is included with Ruby itself. Did you try adding `require 'mail'` to the top of the file?

Comment: Thanks, Can I add configure more than one email address

Comment: Can i configure more than oen email account